# End-date greater than start-date validation android

Tags: android, validation, date, calendar

I have two EditText's. One with start date and other with end date.
I need to make a validation and check if end date is greater than start-date. I don't know how i can do this.

In my code i make the difference bettween two dates in days, and now i also need to check if end date is greater than start-date

Here is my code:

```
             //EditText with string of start date
            dataInicio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ses_dpDataIni);
             //EditText with string of end date
    dataFim = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ses_dpDataFim);

             //Convert String to calendar to check the difference between two dates..
    try{
    dateInic = dataInicio.getText().toString();
    dateFim = dataFim.getText().toString();

    calInic=Calendar.getInstance();
    calFim = Calendar.getInstance();
    calInic.setTime(form.parse(dateInic));
    calFim.setTime(form.parse(dateFim));
    }
     catch (ParseException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    Log.w(SessaoQuotaEdit.class.getName(),"DIFERENCA DE DIAS"  +daysBetween(calInic,calFim));
    tvDiasQuotas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ses_tvNumDiasQuota);
    tvDiasQuotas.setText("NUMBER OF DAYS: " +daysBetween(calInic,calFim));

            //CHECK IS END-DATE IS GREATER THAN START-DATE
             .............
             .............
```

Can you help me?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
public static boolean checkDates("2012-07-12", "2012-06-12)"    {
    boolean b = false;
    try {
        if(dfDate.parse(d1).before(dfDate.parse(d2)))
        {
            b = true;//If start date is before end date
        }
        else if(dfDate.parse(d1).equals(dfDate.parse(d2)))
        {
            b = true;//If two dates are equal
        }
        else
        {
            b = false; //If start date is after the end date
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my day.

Comment: I am using kotlin and mine keeps giving me the exception. can u please help me?

Answer (score 5):

Try this function.

```
public static boolean isDateAfter(String startDate,String endDate)
    {
        try
        {
            String myFormatString = "yyyy-M-dd"; // for example
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
            Date date1 = df.parse(endDate));
            Date startingDate = df.parse(startDate);

            if (date1.after(startingDate))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

It return true if enddate is after start date.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean CheckDates(String d1, String d2){
    SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    boolean b = false;
    try {
        if(dfDate.parse(d1).before(dfDate.parse(d2)))
        {
            b = true;//If start date is before end date
        }
        else if(dfDate.parse(d1).equals(dfDate.parse(d2)))
        {
            b = true;//If two dates are equal
        }
        else
        {
            b = false; //If start date is after the end date
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Some explanations or code comments would improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long%29)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone ....

```
Here is my solution

        if(calInic.after(calFim)==true)
        Log.w(SessaoQuotaEdit.class.getName(),"ERROR: DATA FINAL É ANTES DA DATA INICIAL");
    else
        if(calInic.before(calFim)==true)
            Log.w(SessaoQuotaEdit.class.getName(),"CORRECTO: DATAS CORRECTAS");
        else
            if(calInic.equals(calFim)==true)
                Log.w(SessaoQuotaEdit.class.getName(),"CORRECTO: DATAS IGUAIS");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
***Used Ram kiran Answer***     

public boolean checkDatesBefore(String startDate, String endDate) {
            boolean b = false;
            SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            try {
                if (dfDate.parse(startDate).before(dfDate.parse(endDate))) {
                    b = true;// If start date is before end date
                } else if (dfDate.parse(startDate).equals(dfDate.parse(endDate))) {
                    b = true;// If two dates are equal
                } else {
                    b = false; // If start date is after the end date
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return b;
        }

    checkDatesBefore(startDate,endDate);


    **and check another time for not less than or equals today**

    public boolean checkDatesAfter(String selectedDate, String today) {
            boolean b = false;
            SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            try {
                if (dfDate.parse(selectedDate).compareTo((dfDate.parse(today))) < 0)

           {
                    b = true;// If start date is before end date
                } else if (dfDate.parse(selectedDate).equals(dfDate.parse(today))) {
                    b = true;// If two dates are equal
                } else {
                    b = false; // If start date is after the end date
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return b;
        }
        enter code here

    call checkDatesAfter(selectedDate,today)

    **Best of luck..**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!dateValidation("2016-11-23", "2016-11-24", "yyyy-MM-dd")) {
    // ToastHelper.show("Please select date properly");

    // or do something
}


public static boolean dateValidation(String startDate,String endDate,String dateFormat )
{
    try
    {

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        Date date1 = df.parse(endDate);
        Date startingDate = df.parse(startDate);

        if (date1.after(startingDate))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified Answer of **Ram Kiran**, It will check in one statement only.

```
   public static boolean checkDates(String d1, String d2) {
        SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        boolean b = false;
        try {
            b = dfDate.parse(d1).before(dfDate.parse(d2)) || dfDate.parse(d1).equals(dfDate.parse(d2));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin extension:**

```
fun String.isLessThanEndDate(toDate:String):Boolean {
        val dfDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
        var result = false
        try
        {
            result = dfDate.parse(this).before(dfDate.parse(toDate)) || dfDate.parse(this) == dfDate.parse(toDate)
        }
        catch (e:ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          Calendar startdate = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar enddate = Calendar.getInstance();
                  imgstartcal1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mainActivity, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {


                                        startdate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                                        edtstartdate.setText(dateFormatter.format(startdate.getTime()));
                                       edtenddate.setText(null);

                                    }
                                }, startdate.get(Calendar.YEAR), startdate.get(Calendar.MONTH), startdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                                fromDatePickerDialog.show();
                            }
                        });

          imgendcal1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
          fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mainActivity, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
          public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

          enddate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
          if (startdate.after(enddate) || enddate.equals(startdate)){                                
          edtenddate.getText().toString().equals(null);
          }else{                                                  
    fromDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startdate.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());                                              
          edtenddate.setText(dateFormatter.format(enddate.getTime()));
            }
            }
  }, enddate.get(Calendar.YEAR), startdate.get(Calendar.MONTH),startdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    fromDatePickerDialog.show();
    }
   });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

All the functions are failed on certain testing scenarios...But the actual answer to this question is,

```
public static boolean isDateAfter(Date startDate,Date endDate) {
        if (startDate.getYear() < endDate.getYear()) {
            return false;
        } else if (startDate.getYear() > endDate.getYear()) {
            return true;
        } else if (startDate.getYear() == endDate.getYear()) {
            if (startDate.getMonth() + 1 < endDate.getMonth() + 1) {
                return false;
            } else if (startDate.getMonth() + 1 > endDate.getMonth() + 1) {
                return true;
            } else if (startDate.getMonth() + 1 == endDate.getMonth() + 1) {
                if (startDate.getDate() < endDate.getDate()) {
                    return false;
                } else if (startDate.getDate() > endDate.getDate()) {
                    return true;
                } else if (startDate.getDate() == endDate.getDate()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why add 1 to each side of month comparisons?

Comment: I just added 1 to month because it stores month as array so first month will be counted as 0... It's not necessary but it's required for me for some improvements in my program...