# how to set date for from and to with validation

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-date

I am new to android, can any one post the code for the below scenario.

i have to set date for "from" and "to" with validation, that is "to" date should be greater than "from" and "from" date should be lesser than "to" date. is that possiable.

thanks in advance.

Comment: can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298612/end-date-greater-than-start-date-validation-android .he had similar problem as urs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this like :

```
public class DatePickerFixedDates extends Activity {    

    final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    int maxYear = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int maxMonth = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int maxDay = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    int minYear = 2004;
    int minMonth = 10; 
    int minDay = 25;
    private Button btn;
    private  DatePicker BirthDateDP;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.datepickerfixeddates);
        BirthDateDP = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {       
                int day = BirthDateDP.getDayOfMonth();
                int month = BirthDateDP.getMonth();
                int year = BirthDateDP.getYear();           
            }
        });

        BirthDateDP.init(maxYear , maxMonth, maxDay, new OnDateChangedListener() {

            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
            {           

                if (year < minYear)
                    view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);

                    if (monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear)
                    view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);

                    if (dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth)
                    view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);


                    if (year > maxYear)
                    view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

                    if (monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear)
                    view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

                    if (dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth)
                    view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
            }
        });        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i have used two datepicker one is for "from" and other is for "to" in that case how to do

Comment: why u have to use two datepickers? what's ur requirement??

Comment: for applying leave i need from and to, so i need  two datepickers.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean checkIfEndDateIsAfter(String startDate,String endDate)
{
    try
    {
        String myFormatString = "MM-dd-yy"; // for example
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
        Date endingDate = dateFormat.parse(endDate);
        Date startingDate = dateFormat.parse(startDate);

        if (date1.after(startingDate)) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (date1.equals(startingDate)) {
            return true; //some instances it is okay for it to be the same
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        return false;
    }
}
```