# Firebase data validation based on timestamps

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, firebase-security

I need a validation rule that checks if the end date is after the start date, so the period is valid. I have found a couple resources, but I couldn't use them to get what I need. Perhaps for someone else it is of some use.

- https://medium.com/@khreniak/advanced-examples-of-using-cloud-firestore-security-rules-9e641d023c7e
- [End-date greater than start-date validation android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298612/end-date-greater-than-start-date-validation-android)

Basically, I have document coming in in cloud firestore and I need to check if the value dateEnd > dateStart. Both come from the same request. I would rather store the values as day/month/year instead of storing them as a timestamp value. However, if there is no other solution than to use timestamps, I could  use that.

I can't get any further than this:

```
match /organisations/{orgID}/people/{userID} {
    allow create: if(dateEnd > dateStart)
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a date format like YYYYMMDD (which allows to [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) dates), the following should do the trick. It would also work with timestamps in milliseconds.

```
match /organisations/{orgID}/people/{userID}
  allow create: if request.resource.data.dateEnd > request.resource.data.dateStart;
}
```

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation), "When writing data ... the `request.resource` variable contains the future state of the document".

I would suggest you watch the [official video about security rules](https://youtu.be/eW5MdE3ZcAw), a must watch...

---

If you absolutely need to store the values as DD/MM/YYYY in the Firestore document you should have two pairs of fields: a `dateEnd`/`dateStart` pair of field with format DD/MM/YYYY, and another pair of fields, e.g. `dateEndForRules`/`dateStartForRules` with format YYYYMMDD that you only use in the Security rules.

Comment: Is there also a way to get the right values within the security rule? Like change YYYY-MM-DD into YYYYMMDD? Or is that something that should be done in the frontend?

Comment: Yes you can use date values in the YYYY-MM-DD format in the security rule, since it also allows a lexicographical ordering. Adding hyphens doesn’t change the order.